My media queries in sass are overriding my other mixins
I am trying to add some media queries to my scss rules, however when I include the mixins I imported frrom my _index.scss file(which includes my breakpoints file), the media query overrides my previous mixins I used.
@use '../abstracts' as a;
    

    .portfolio_heroSection{
        height:100dvh;
        width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color: a.$background-color1;
        .portfolio_heroSection_top{
            @include a.gridContact;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding-top:4rem;
            width:90%;
            @include a.xs{
                grid-template-columns:1fr;
                grid-template-rows:repeat(2,1fr);
            }
             .portfolio_heroSection_grid{
                text-align:left;
                background-image: url("https://images4.alphacoders.com/130/1303494.jpeg");
                background-position: center;
                background-size: cover;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                padding-top:20rem;
                padding-bottom:18rem;
                padding-left:4rem;
                padding-right:4rem;
                h2{
                    @include a.fontHeader;
                    font-weight:550;
                    font-size:3rem;
                }
            }
         }    
    }

Here is my breakpoints file:
$breakpoints: (
  "xs":0,
  "sm":30rem,
  "md":45rem,
  "lg":60rem,
  "xlg":75rem,
);

@mixin xs(){
  @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints,"xs")){
    @content;
 }
}

@mixin sm(){
  @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints,"sm")){
    @content;
 }
}

@mixin md(){
  @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints,"md")){
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin lg(){
  @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints,"lg")){
    @content;
 }
}

@mixin xlg(){
  @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints,"xlg")){
    @content;
 }
}

@mixin breakpoint($bp:0){
  @media (min-width: $bp){
    @content;
 }
}

I tried to sort the inclusion differently. I attempted to include the media query both before and after the original mixin, and the result is still the media query overiding everything. I really have no idea why this is happening so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
